# Private and protected methods in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, methods, visibility, conventions

What is the recommended way to define private and protected methods in Objective-C? One website suggested using categories in the implementation file for private methods, another suggested trailing underscores, or XX_ where XX is some project-specific code. What does Apple itself use?

And what about protected methods? One solution I read was to use categories in separate files, for example CLASS_protected.h and CLASS_protected.m but this seems like it could get very bloated. What should I do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are three issues:

1. Hiding from compiler.

   That is, making it impossible for someone else to #import something and see your method declarations.   For that, put your private API into a separate header file, mark that header's role as "Private" in Xcode, and then import it in your project where you need access to said private API.

   Use a category or class extension to declare the additional methods.
2. Preventing collisions

   If you are implementing lots of internal goop, do so with a common prefix or something that makes a collision with Apple provided (or third party) provided methods exceedingly unlikely.  This is especially critical for categories and not nearly as critical for your leaf node subclasses of existing classes.

   Post the link for the site suggesting leading underscores, as they are wrong, wrong, wrong.  Leading underscores are used by the system to mark private API and you can run into collisions easily enough.
3. Hiding from the runtime.

   Don't bother.  It just makes debugging / crash analysis harder and anyone determined enough to muck around at the runtime will be able to hack your app anyway.

Comment: Here's the requested link: http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-08-27-defensive-programming-in-cocoa.html#comment-e3aef3e1036c9c396edc208415223f01

Answer (score 1):

There are no "real" private methods in Objective C, as the run-time will allow, via documented public APIs, access any method in any class by using their string names.

I never do separate interface files for "private" methods, and let the compiler complain if I try to use these any of these methods outside of file scope.

The XX_ seems to be the ad hoc means to create a pseudo namespace.  The idea is to read Apple's docs and the docs of any frameworks you might use at any time in the future, and pick an XX prefix that none of these others is ever likely to use.